# How to print a wordpress query?

Tags: wordpress

I have a while loop in my wordpress site. How to print its query details ?

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

I tried, but not working:

```
print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']->request);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612) in your `functions.php` then add `?debug=sql` after the `url`, for example

```
http://someUrl.com/something?debug=sql
```

Or

```
http://localhost/localCopy?debug=sql
```

Also `<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>` should work, just put it right after the loop if you didn't it before.